# Count Occurrences of Character "?" in r

Tags: r, count, frequency, find-occurrences

Newbie r question..

I'm looking to generate a frequency count of the number of occurrences of "?" within my data set.

Should look something like this:

```
encounter_id 0
patient_nbr 0
race 2273
gender 0
weight 98569
```

I used the following to get a count for the column "weight" but would like a more stream-lined approach to counting all "?" for all columns.. I don't want to have to retype the below function for EACH column..

```
table(dataset$weight[dataset$weight=="?"])
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just do a sum `sum(dataset$weight == "?")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
dataset$weight_questmark <- ifelse(dataset$weight == "?", 1, 0)
sum(dataset$weight_questmark)
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But what if I want to apply this function to all columns?

Comment: `find_quest <- function(x) sum(x == "?") `  and `sapply(dataset, find_quest)`